# Python： How do string variables prevent escape?

Tags: python

```
>>>m = "\frac{7x+5}{1+y^2}"
>>>print(m)
rac{7x+5}{1+y^2}
>>>print(r""+m)
rac{7x+5}{1+y^2}
>>>print(r"{}".format(m))
rac{7x+5}{1+y^2}
>>>print(repr(m))
'\x0crac{7x+5}{1+y^2}'
```

I want the result:"\frac{7x+5}{1+y^2}"
Must be a string variable!!!

Comment: Use a 'raw' (`r`-prefixed) string, or double the backslash.  You have to apply the `r` to the string *actually containing the backslash* - you can't fix the problem later, because the backslash had already been removed from the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need the string literal that contains the slash to be a raw string.

```
m = r"\frac{7x+5}{1+y^2}"
```

Raw strings are just another way of writing strings. They aren't a different type. For example `r""` is exactly the same as `""` because there are no characters to escape, it doesn't produce some kind of raw empty string and adding it to another string changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the escape sign to the escape sign to signify that it is a string literal

```
m = "\\frac{7x+5}{1+y^2}"
print(m)
print(r""+m)
print(r"{}".format(m))
print(repr(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is to read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). So you can use either the escape character "\" as here

```
>>> m = "\\frac{7x+5}{1+y^2}"
>>> print(m)
\frac{7x+5}{1+y^2}
```

or use string literals, which takes the string to be as is

```
>>> m = r"\frac{7x+5}{1+y^2}"
>>> print(m)
\frac{7x+5}{1+y^2}
```